# Is JavaScript test() saving state in the regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Open up a browser console and execute the following code:

```
var foo = /foo/g;
```

Then,

```
foo.test("foo") // true
```

Then,

```
foo.test("foo") // false
```

If you continue to execute foo.test("foo"), you will see alternating true/false responses as if the var foo is actually being modified.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that's how `.test()` and `.exec()` work when the regex is `g` global. They start at the end of the last match.

You can observe the current last index on the regular expression object using the `.lastIndex` property.

It's a writeable property, so you can reset it to `0` when/if you need. When the regex is run without finding a match, it automatically resets to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The regex keeps the position of the last test. This allows searching of long strings. You can reset this by setting lastIndex = 0;