# Does RegExp has some internal state?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var leMessage = 'command';

var lePattern = new RegExp('command','gi');

var leBanane;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   leBanane = lePattern.exec(leMessage) === null ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL";
    console.log(leBanane);
}
```

and it outputs this:

```
$ node main.js                                                                                                                                            
NOT NULL                                                                                                                                                        
NULL                                                                                                                                                            
NOT NULL                                                                                                                                                        
NULL                                                                                                                                                            
NOT NULL                                                                                                                                                        
NULL                                                                                                                                                            
NOT NULL                                                                                                                                                        
NULL                                                                                                                                                            
NOT NULL                                                                                                                                                        
NULL
```

Why does it return nulls? The behavior I expected was for it to return something != null since it is a match. What the hell...

Comment: See also [Is JavaScript test() saving state in the regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15276873/1048572)

Comment: I searched a lot for this, still couldn't find those topics...! Thanks!